JPA Many to many with just a list of ids
For the purpose of simplifying the problem, consider that I have a Location aggregate, which can exist independently. Here’s an example:
class LocationId {
   String value;
}

class Location {
   LocationId value;
   // other attributes
}

Also a Person class, which can be associated with zero or more Location instances. In a pure object-oriented model, I would have something like this:
class PersonId {
   String value;
}

class Person {
   PersonId id;
   List<LocationId> locations;

   void addLocation(Location location) {
      // perform checks on location
      // associate location id with person
   }

   void removeLocation(Location location) {
      // perform checks on location
      // disassociate location id from person
   }
}


To map these models to the database, I would use the following structure:

location table with a primary key (id)
person table with a primary key (id)
person_location table (with person_id and location_id as foreign keys to person and location)

My question is

How can I map the locations property to the database without modifying my domain model classes, just by adding annotations?

The closest I got was using this approach.

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
  name = "person_location",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
)
@AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "location_id"))

However, when generating the tables, the foreign key is only created from person_location.person_id to person.id, missing the foreign key from person_location.location_id to location.id.
Hibernate:
    alter table if exists person_location
       add constraint FK6ftdgrcrspx1gl3qfvmsdtqru        
       foreign key (person_id)
       references person


Another possibile solution would be to have the entire Location inside Person. However, in my domain model I just don't need to have the entire location inside Person.

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "person_location",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "location_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
private List<Location> locations;

Github repository Just run and check application log startup

You are trying too hard. JPA entities usually map what your table structure is, which in this case, is a M:M between Location and Person (not their IDs). Your JPA provider then will understand that the join table has to have FKs between these two tables, and order the inserts/updates and deletes appropriately.  Jackson/JSON mappers can create JSON from these entities that only includes lists of the IDs, not the full entities, or you can create and map these entities to DTOs can do this yourself.

Previously, I had not understood what you wanted to achieve.
In order to reflect a many-to-many relationship in JPA, one of the ways is to use ManyToMany with a JoinTable. Note that Location, rather than LocationId is used in:
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "person_location",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "location_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
private List<Location> locations;

Now, you had some mistakes that prevented your code from running, even after this change.
All entities have to have a protected/public no-args constructor.
As in the following example:
public Person() {
    this.locations = Collections.emptyList();        
}


Thanks!
Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Error: An association that targets entity 'person' from entity 'person' has 2 '@JoinColumn's but the primary key has 1 columns

Added github repo link to simulate the problem.
https://github.com/murilocardoso/jpalistvalueobjectid

Thanks N Sarj. I am aware of the solution you propose but it changes my domain model. I don't need the entire Location inside Person. I have no problem to run the application, person and location have no-args constructor as private. Did you try to run?

I added information in the original post indicating that I am aware of the solution you propose

You don't need to have the entire location in memory. The correct approach is to have a reference (and a back reference) to the entity and not the key values.

imho, this is the orm correct approach and not the domain model correct approach. Person and Location are two different aggregates and according to this view they should be related only by ID and in an unidirectional way.
